# Filling a C# struct array with multiple values at once

Tags: c#, struct

I have a struct array which looks like this:

```
    public struct DATA
    {
        public int number;
        public int channel;
        public string filename;
        public string description;
    }
    DATA[] myData = new DATA[12];
```

I need to fill a lot of values in here, for example myData[0] = {0, 1, "myfile", "TBD"} etc.

What is the easiest way (in terms of LOC) to fill these 12 structs with data? Would it be easier to use a class instead?

Comment: Insufficient data. What is your current process? Must you implement this in a linear-code fashion, for each item? Or can you use a loop to iterate and populate?

Comment: I highly recommend you make this `struct` immutable by making those fields public properties with private setters! (That's right; I *did* just make a recommendation having no idea what your specific scenario is. That's because this is the correct thing to do about 95% of the time.)

Comment: I cannot loop through the items, because the data looks like this: "myData[0] is "0, 1, "myfile", "TBD"" myData[1] "0, 2, "myXYfile" "ABC" etc. This would require a lot of loops and a lot of unreadable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C method to do this doesn't work.

```
DATA[] myData = new DATA[]{{1,3,"asdasd","asdasd"}, {...
```

You have to set every single DATA struct.

I suggest to add a constructor

```
public DATA(int number, int channel, string filename, string description)
{
    this.number = number;
    this.channel = channel;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.description = description;
}
```

and fill the array using the ctor

```
DATA[] myData = new DATA[]{
    new DATA(1,  3,  "abc",  "def"),
    new DATA(2, 33, "abcd", "defg"),
    ...
};
```

You can also use a generic list and initilize it this way (.NET 3.5 and later):

```
List<DATA> list = new List<DATA>()
{
    new DATA(1,  3,  "abc",  "def"),
    new DATA(2, 33, "abcd", "defg")
};
```

Comment: how can i access the values like this method?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a constructor for a struct:

```
 public struct DATA
    {
        public int number;
        public int channel;
        public string filename;
        public string description;

        public DATA(int theNumber, int theChannel, ...)
        {
           number = theNumber;
           channel = theChannel;
           ...
        }

    }
```

You might then also find a List more useful:

```
List<DATA> list = new List<DATA>();

list.Add(new DATA(1,2,...));
```

Then:

```
DATA[] data = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop will probably work best:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myData.Length; i++)
 {
    myData[i] = new DATA() { number = i, channel = i + 1, filename = "TMP", description = "TBD"};
 }
```